# Can we do a Sum on CharField in Django ORM?

Tags: django, django-orm

My model in Django ORM is this

```
class Test(Modelbase):
    id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to add the amount for list of id's. The only problem is the amount field is **CharField**. How do I apply sum for the **amount** field?

```
Test.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3]).aggregate(Sum('amount'))
```

I am using `Django=1.9.1` for this.

Comment: how would you add characters? and why is amount a char field? shouldn't it be a integer or float?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Yes the amount should be in float field. But we cannot change it now. There was some other taught process for it.

Comment: Change your `CharField()` into `IntegerField()`, In case you don't want to lose data, just add a second field named `amount2` as `IntegerField` (run makemigrations) then loop through them by adding the value of `amount` to `amount2`. After the loop, now remove the field `amount` (run make migrations), rename `amount2` to `amount` `(run make migrations)`, and you good to go with SUM.. this is a little bit tricky, you will end up with an `IntergerField` able to use `Sum`

Comment: What is `Modelbase` here?

Comment: @Lemayzeur Yes I can do that no doubt. However, I was wondering without doing migrations if we could have a workaround. I tried with RawSQL and it works.

Comment: maybe with python `sum`, but this isn't totally django ORM. `values_list('amout',flat=True)`, and use `sum()`

Comment: @Lemayzeur Yes true. This too is a workaround.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can try do `annotate` with [cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#cast):

```
from django.db.models import FloatField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

Test.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3]
    ).annotate(as_float=Cast('amount', FloatField())
    ).aggregate(Sum('as_float'))
```

**Note** for django < 1.10, you should define `Cast` here the [source Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/db/models/functions/base/#Cast)
Or

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Func, F

Test.objects.annotate(
    num=Func(
        F('amount'),
        template='%(function)s(%(expressions)s AS %(type)s)',
        function='Cast', type='float')
   ).aggregate(Sum('num'))
```

Comment: Cannot import Cast in this Django version.

Comment: Can we use extra and then aggregate?

Comment: glad to help you.

Comment: You made my day. awesome